Variables from buffer in nodejs
I am studying pure nodejs, no express, no fastify  and other frameworks that's why I don't need npm mutler and file-upload.
I am sending 2-3 mp3 files and two txt files from a client side to a nodejs server. I successfully get them as a buffer. Then I need to take them from the buffer and put them in variables. But I don't know how to do it.
I tried using some buffer methods but they didn't help me with a buffer of different types of files, so I failed to get variables from it.
What I learned is  how to save data from the buffer into a file.
           r.on("data", chunk =>{                 
                body.push(chunk)  
                
           });
            r.on("end", ()=>{  
                let data = Buffer.concat(body);
                writeableStream.write(data);
           })  

This code can save only one file.
But I need to get files as variables before saving them onto disk. Could you possibly give some ideas how get variables from a buffer with different files

A buffer is a type of object that you have in a variable. Perhaps you mean you need to get it as a string in a variable? Or perhaps you're using multipart/form-data encoding to send several files to the server and wonder how to read out the multiple files from the single Buffer? Please clarify your question.

Yes, I do need to get files from one single buffer as separate variables.  One buffer is divided into 3-5 variables.  How can I see the boundaries between the chunks in the buffer so that i could slice it and convert the chunks to variables?

Are you using multipart/form-data encoding? If you're using a simple html form with <input type=file, you should make sure that's the case, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#enctype

Yes, I do.  And I get my files as one single buffer on server side.

Sounds like this question. If you want to implement parsing that yourself as an exercise, the specification is RFC 7578. It's a pretty old format (unlike XML or JSON). A more gentle introduction is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Here is a great example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#multipartform-data

Thank you for answers, i am already studying busboy hoping it will help me do something like it. Busboy deals with chunks coming to the server, but I want to deal with a complete buffer filled with  files in it. Sounds a bit different. I wanted to cut it into chunks correspondint to sizes of files in it/ and then deal with each of them.
